# Panels is still adding sidebars

Tags: panels, nodes, 7

Here is what we are doing:

1. We are working to build a new theme for the website we are working on.
2. We are using ThemeKey and Context to utilize the areas of the new given content types / drupal paths we are using for the new theme instead of Panels.
3. Panels previously owned the pages we are building on.

**For Some Reason, sidebars/blocks (from the previous panel) is still printing to the $content tag for the new theme.**

Any Ideas?  It's somewhat hard to describe the behavior over this platform, if you ask questions, I promise to answer them quickly until the problem is resolved...

Comment: Please identify which version of Drupal and panels you are using?  I assume panels remain enabled?

Comment: Drupal 6, Panels 6.x-3.9, and panels is enabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inherited this site.

In the Panels Page Manager, rules were set up for "node/#."
Therefore, any new node was printing blocks as a sidebar because of those set rules. I reconfigured those rules, and the problem has been fixed.